# Returning a callback and calling a callback inside a promise chain in AJAX request

Tags: ajax, callback, promise, react-redux, axios

I was working on a react project and the following three cases came up. Can someone give me some pointers as to what the differences are when making AJAX request using axios as well as redux-promise?

```
Case 1 (the payload is undefined - why?): 
axios.get(link) 
.then(callback)

Case 2 (the payload is also undefined - why?): 
axios.get(link)
.then(() => callback())

Case 3 (the payload is the res object): 
axios.get(link)
.then((res) => { callback; return res });
```

Would really appreciate if anyone could please answer this question or give me pointers to materials that could clear my confusion. I did my best researching and have spent couple hours before I posted the question on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolved value in the first two promises is `undefined` because you have a `.then()` handler that you don't return anything from.  The `return` value of the `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of the promise chain.

If you want `link` to be the resolved value of the promise and you're going to have your own `.then()` handler, then you have to return it.

**Case 1:**

```
axios.get(link).then(callback)
```

Here you're delegating your `.then()` handler to the callback function.  Unless it returns the value it was passed to it (which apparently it doesn't), then the return value from your `.then()` handler is `undefined` and thus that's what the resolved value of the promise chain becomes.

Case 1 is equivalent to this:

```
axios.get(link).then(function(val) {
    return callback(val);
});
```

So, the promise chain takes on whatever `callback(val)` returns as the resolved value.

**Case 2:**

```
axios.get(link).then(() => callback())
```

Here, we can clearly see that the return value from the `.then()` arrow function handler is the result of executing `callback()` which is apparently `undefined` so thus the promise chain takes on a resolved value of `undefined`.

You could fix that by doing this:

```
axios.get(link).then(() => {
    callback()
    return link;
});
```

**Case 3:**

```
axios.get(link).then((res) => { callback; return res });
```

Here's you're explicitly returning `res` so that becomes the resolved value of the promise chain.  You're also not even calling `callback()`.  I presume you meant to have `()` after it.

**Don't mix plain callbacks in with promises**

You also probably don't want to mix plain callbacks with promises and they are two different approaches to asynchronous notification and it's much better to use only one technique in a given section of code.  Instead, turn the callback operation into one that returns a promise that is resolved when the callback would normally get called.  Then, you can just chain promises.

Or, if you're trying to notify some caller about the completion of the operation, then have them just watch the returned promise with their own `.then()` handler on the returned promise.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, thank you so much for your detailed explanations. I just took some time to read through it and it really helps clear things up. I am eternally grateful :)